# join 2 query results orderby two different values

Tags: c#, linq, join, sql-order-by

Assuming this object:

```
DXMessage
{
    public byte[] msg;
    public int time;
    public int millisecond;
}
```

and assuming that I have 2 sorted lists:

```
public static SortedList<long, DXMessage> brimstoneMessages = 
            new SortedList<long, DXMessage>();

public static SortedList<long, DXMessage> gpsMessages =
            new SortedList<long, DXMessage>();
```

I have executed 2 queries on 2 different lists of messages:

```
var bsQuery = GlobalObjects.bsMessages.Where(t =>
            ((t.Value.Time >= eventStart))).ToList();

var gpsQuery = GlobalObjects.gpsMessages.Where(t =>
            ((t.Value.Time >= eventStart))).ToList();
```

I would like to take the results of these 2 queries, and join them in ascending order by Time and millisecond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "join" do you mean "concatenate" rather than a sort of SQL join? I suspect you just want:

```
var combined = bsQuery.Concat(gpsQuery)
                      .OrderBy(x => x.Value.time)
                      .ThenBy(x => x.Value.millisecond);
```

It's not clear why you've got so many brackets in your queries by the way - and in this case it looks like you could *actually* perform the combination earlier:

```
var combined = GlobalObjects.bsMessages
                            .Concat(GlobalObjects.gpsMessages)
                            .Where(t => t.Value.Time >= eventStart)
                            .OrderBy(t => t.Value.Time)
                            .ThenBy(t => t.Value.Millisecond);
```

Comment: /@Soner, 
I'm sure you guys are right on this.  Like i mentioned before, I don't have a lot of experience with Linq.  I'm not surprised that i don't even know the correct terminology.  It will take me a bit to change my code around to accept this information, but i'm gonna go ahead and mark this as an answer.

Comment: and @Jon!.  New to the site too, so gotta make sure and mention you too.

Comment: I'm intending on grabbing the KeyValuePair.  My queries has been modified accordingly

Comment: @Jason: Ah, okay, so they're not lists of messages as such... editing.